# Error type mismatch, java.lang.String[][] does not match with java.lang.String[]

Tags: java, arrays, processing

```
Table table;
String N;
String F;
String data;
String[] test = new String[1];
String stringcolumn;

//Here is where I assign all the variables.

void setup() {

  table = loadTable("CVSTEST.csv", "header");
  int rows = table.getRowCount();
  int columns = table.getColumnCount();

  //Get the row count and the table

  for(int column = 0; column <= columns; column++){
    for(int row = 0; row <= rows; row++){

          //For every row in every column, assign data the input for later use

          data = table.getString(rows,columns);
          stringcolumn = Integer.toString(column);
          test = new String[stringcolumn][data];

          //Here is where the error occurs, I try to assign string column and data to the string array of test.

    }
  }
}
```

So I've been stuck on this one for a while. I am making a program that prints out data as you put it in the table, E.G

```
Name Score
Tim  513
```

but I keep running into this error. I am saving as a float in order to keep it organised, and so printing it out is easier in the future, and I can use the data in later code, and use it for comparisons later. Cheers.

Comment: `test` is declared as `String[]` i.e. a one-dimension array, but you are attempting to assign `new String[stringcolumn][data]`, a 2-dimension array to it.  This is not correct. What is your question?  What don't you understand?  Please remember that StackOverflow is not a tutorial site.  Visit the [help] and read [ask] for details.

Comment: I know Jim, but the problem still remains. How would I set a 2 dimension array? If java counts up from 0, would 1 not be a 2 dimension array of 0 and 1, therefore being String[1] instead of String[2]? I know it is not correct, which is why I need help with it, and thus why I asked.

Comment: You're confusing index, which is 0-based, and length, which is 1-based. You're also confusing length with dimensions. `new String[2]` creates a 1-dimensional, 2-element array, supporting indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: Hey Nobody, I'm afraid I'll have to agree with Jim. If you don't know the difference between a 1-dimensional array and a 2-dimensional array, you are clearly lacking some very fundamental concepts. At this point, you should really consult a good tutorial or book instead of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Look what I've found for you: [processing's array tutorial](https://processing.org:8443/tutorials/arrays/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you're going through an array. The `Table` class already contains functions that allow you to access the data from an index. But even if you're trying to do something slightly different, hopefully this helps:

You've got a few problems. First off:

```
String[] test = new String[1];
```

This declares your `test` variable to be a one-dimensional `String` array, with a length of 1, which doesn't make a ton of sense: why do you need an array if it's only going to store a single value?

If you want to declare it as a two-dimensional `String` array, you would do this:

```
String[][] test;
```

Note that this declares the array, but it doesn't initialize it yet. To initialize it, you probably want to know the size of the 2D array. I'm assuming you want to use the column and row count from the table? If so, you would do this:

```
void setup() {

  table = loadTable("CVSTEST.csv", "header");
  int rows = table.getRowCount();
  int columns = table.getColumnCount();

  test = new String[rows][columns];
```

Now your `test` variable is a two-dimensional array, which you can think of as an array of arrays.

Next, this line makes no sense:

```
test = new String[stringcolumn][data];
```

What are you trying to do here? Since this is inside your nested `for` loop, this is trying to create a new two-dimensional array for each cell in the table. I would guess that what you really want to do is have one two-dimensional array, and you'd populate its indexes inside this nested `for` loop. Something like this:

```
test[row][column] = data;
```

This sets the index at position `[row][column]` equal to whatever `String` is in the `data` variable.